# Not able to launch the AVD in Mac OS Mojave

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

Recently was facing issue in launching the AVD in the Mac OS Mojave, every time was getting the below issue.

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name [Pixel_C_API_28], use -list-avds to see valid list.
```

***Solution:***
Google or Stack overflow was also not much helpful, after a couple of days long debugging found out that my ANDROID_SDK_HOME was wrongly set. Once, I fixed by updating to proper location, it started working. Thought it will be useful to someone, that is the reason posting here.